# How to split a single row into multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, split, row, multiple-columns

In Excel, I want to split up the data in row 1 into four single columns. A1:D1 should remain in place. E1:H1 should become A2:D2 and so on.

I am currently using this formula in A2:

```
INDEX($1:$1;(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN()-1)
```

... But I am getting a `#REF!` error.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this formula in Cell `A2` (you may need to use semicolon instead of commas in non-English version of Excel)

`=OFFSET(A$1,0,(ROW()-1)*4)`

Then, copy & paste or drag the formula across columns B thru D, as many rows as you need.

[image]

Alternatively, your formula (`=INDEX($1:$1,(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN()-1)`), is not returning an error for me, however it is not returning the correct column. If you prefer the Index function you can use:

`=INDEX($1:$1,(ROW()-1)*4+COLUMN())`

Substitute semicolons for commas if needed.

Comment: @Aarav you're welcome! Do consider "accepting" the answer if it has helped you.  Cheers.